# Dropdown without model in yii

Tags: yii

I am using a component for parsing a country api in yii. So in the form drop down list call the function for listing country. The function returned country list as array.
form.php

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'country'); ?>
<?php $cty=  Country::getCountry();
      echo $form->dropdownList($model,'country', $cty , array('style'=>'width: 175px','empty'=>array('empty'=>Yii::t('app','Select Country'))));?>
```

Now the country list loaded correctly in drop down, but when on saving time the corresponding id of country is saved. i want to save the country name in db.How it solved?

Comment: What does `Country` look like? Why save the name if the primary key for a country is its id?

Comment: <?php
 $new= Country::getCountry();
 foreach($new as $strn)
    {
    print_r($new);
    echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
Its a component function, returns country list as array. The output like this Array ( [0] => Afghanistan [1] => Aland Islands [2] => Albania [3] => Algeria [4] => American Samoa

Answer (score 2):

You have to build your own custom array with the needed keys/values, e.g. :

```
$cty = Country::getCountry();
$cty = array_combine(array_values($cty), $cty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way (in case if you need all items of Country table)

```
$cty = CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'name', 'name');
```